# What mechanism to use for push-messages?

Tags: android, networking, push-notification

This is not a question for a ready-to-use solution including sources but for getting ideas/hints/tips for a solution.

Assumed I have a messenger. User A types some text that has to be sent to user B. This text is sent to a central server first where it is stored when user B is not online or where it has to be transmitted to user B immediately when he is available.

For second case, what mechanism should be used here on a mobile device?

1.) Let the messenger of user B open a client connection to the server and to permanently receive data from there does not sound good to me. When the connection is interrupted it has to be re-established - possible until next interruption. So establishing of such a connection may cause traffic and consume power without transporting any payload in between.

2.) Let the messenger use a ServerSocket and let the central "server" connect to the device has the same problems: the connection may be interrupted.

So my question: is there a mechanism available for mobile devices that transmits such messages only in case they are available and establishes a connection only when it is needed? Some kind of automated push-notification without permanent connection between client and server?

Comment: Have you read about GCM provided by android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recomended to use [GCM for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) You have nice tutorial. You could also use frameworks like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Either
1. Have a persistent connection between client and the server. Client can poll at a predifined interval to check incoming payload. You may have to optimize the 'poll' logic to avoid frequent 'poll' payload

Or

1. Server side may push a WAP push to the client when messages are available, then the client wakes up and retreive the payload.

Answer (score 0):

don't use Polling. Use Google Cloud Messaging. suseba answer references to gcm deprecated in the "Here" link.

Use GoogleCloudMessaging. comes with GooglePlayServices Library

Documentation : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

and the source is: https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git%2Fgcm-client

you just need to import libraries